# How to convert the arff object loaded from a .arff file into a dataframe format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arff

I was able to load the .arff file using the following commands. But I was not able to extract the data from the object and convert the object into a dataframe format. I need this to do apply machine learning algorithms on this dataframe.

Command:-

```
import arff
dataset = pd.DataFrame(arff.load(open('Training Dataset.arff')))
print(dataset)
```

Please help me to convert the data from here into a dataframe.

Answer (score 17):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff 

raw_data = loadarff('Training Dataset.arff')
df_data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data[0])
```

Try this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff
import pandas as pd

data = loadarff('Training Dataset.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
```

Similar to answer above, but no need to import numpy

Comment: The import statement is incorrect. This will not run b/c in line 4 `arff` is not defined.